# is it possible to run the batch apex without using the start method in salesforce?

Tags: batch

without using  the start method to run the batch Apex. how to solve the above scenario please give some ideas.

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: What really is your use case? Why would you think of running batch without start method? The more info you give us the easier it would be for us to suggest you a solution

Answer (score 3):

You can not implement a batch without `start` method. This method is part of "`Batchable`" interface and mandatory to define. Read following link for [Batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm):

- [Batchable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchable.htm)
- [Batch Apex Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_batch_intro.htm)

> To write a batch Apex class, your class must implement the
>   Database.Batchable interface. Your class declaration must include the
>   implements keyword followed by Database.Batchable.
>
> You must also implement three methods:
>
> - start()
> - execute()
> - finish()

Answer (score 1):

The `start` method returns the items that are broken up into batches and passed into the `execute` method. So the `start` has to return at least one item for the `Batchable` to have much purpose. But because `start` can return an `Iterable`, it could say return the numbers 1 to 10 or the letters a to z. The `execute` doesn't even have to use the values passed in to it.

Comment: using this three methods how to run the batch apex in salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Normally the class which implements the interface, should implement/define all the  methods available in the interface.

Comment: how to run the batchOpportunityUpdate in batch apex

Comment: iam getting these error like........................ Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Name at line 13 column 14

Comment: can you please give me one example